# Creating a function which will merge all the object parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I want to make a function which can take any number of arguments. I can make function with fix arguments but I'm not able to solve with n arguments.

Example:

```
const first = { x: 2, y: 3};
const second = { a: 70, x: 4, z: 5 };
const third = { x: 0, y: 9, q: 10 };

const firstSecondThird = extend(first, second, third);
// { x: 2, y: 3, a: 70, z: 5, q: 10 }

const secondThird = extend(second, third);
// { a: 70, x: 4, z: 5, y: 9, q: 10 }`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: So Object assign in reverse?

Comment: @YongQuan that one is for fixed arguments i want to make function with n arguments.

Comment: It's not clear: are you asking about how to merge objects? Or are you asking about how to handle a variable number of function parameters?

Comment: @BarotShalin have you read _all_ the listed answers?

Comment: @DanielBeck i want to merge objects without overwriting and with n arguments. I can solve for fixed arguments.

Comment: You may want to re-think what you are trying to do. As opposed to creating a function that can have a dynamic amount of parameters, give the function an object or an array that contains all the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to get all the parameters into an array and then use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) inside a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to merge them recursively:

```js
const first = { x: 2, y: 3},
      second = { a: 70, x: 4, z: 5 },
      third = { x: 0, y: 9, q: 10 };

const extend = (...params) => params.reduce((r,p) => ({ ...r, ...p }), {})

console.log(extend(first, second, third))
console.log(extend(second, third))
```

If you want to give preference to the properties of earlier objects, then you have to [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the `arguments` before using `reduce`:

```js
const first = { x: 2, y: 3},
      second = { a: 70, x: 4, z: 5 },
      third = { x: 0, y: 9, q: 10 };

const extend = (...params) => params.reverse().reduce((r, p) => ({ ...r, ...p}), {})

console.log(extend(first, second, third))
console.log(extend(second, third))
```

Comment: You will need to reverse the order of the parameters to get OP's expected results.

Comment: @adiga Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @adiga I also have to throw error if any argument is undefined or if arguments are less than 2. can you help me with that

Comment: Inside the `extend` throw error if `params.length` is < 2 and inside `reduce` throw error if `p` is `undefined`